# Criteria for Zariski density of subgroups of reductive groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a number field $K$. Let $\Gamma\subset G(K)$ be a subgroup.

My extremely naive question is - When can you deduce that $\Gamma$ is Zariski-dense? I'm looking for criteria for Zariski-density, possibly making additional assumptions on $G,K,\Gamma$.

To my surprise I've found it to be very difficult to find information on this question. References would also be appreciated!

As a special case of this, let $R_K\subset K$ be the ring of integers. Fix an embedding of algebraic $K$-groups $i : G\hookrightarrow \text{GL}_{n,K}$, and define $G(R_K) := \text{GL}_n(R_K)\cap i(G(K))$. When is $G(R_K)$ Zariski-dense? Does it depend on the embedding $i$?

It might be appropriate to make this a community wiki

Answer (score 7):

The groups $G(R_K)$ you are interested in are arithmetic groups.  If $G$ is semisimple, then a theorem of Borel and Harish-Chandra says that $G(R_K)$ is a lattice in $G(K \otimes \mathbb{R})$.  Modulo some other minor hypotheses (connected, no compact factors) you can then appeal to the Borel Density Theorem to see that $G(R_K)$ is Zariski dense in $G(K \otimes \mathbb{R})$.  A nice source that discusses this kind of thing is Dave Witte-Morris's book "Introduction to Arithmetic groups", available [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0106063)

For this, you definitely need $G$ to be semisimple.  For instance, $GL(n,\mathbb{Z})$ is not Zariski dense in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ (and is also not a lattice).

Comment: Do you mean to say that $G(R_K)$ is Zariski dense in $G$? The Borel density theorem seems to only address the case that $K$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}$. What if $K$ is imaginary?

Comment: @stupid_question_bot: Use Weil Restriction is to reduce to the case $K=\mathbb{Q}$. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_restriction